# Concatenate strings of different length into one

Tags: r, paste

I have two character objects of different length:

```
a <- "A"
bc <- c("B","C")
```

Now I would like to concatenate these in such a manner that I get `"ABC"`, but `paste()` repeats `a` as many times as `length(bc)`:

```
paste("a",c("b","c"),collapse="", sep="")
> "ABAC"
```

Anyone an idea on how to get `"ABC"` instead of `"ABAC"`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
> paste(c(a,bc), collapse="", sep="")
[1] "ABC"
```

Comment: Or `paste0(c(a,bc), collapse="")` in newer versions of `R`.